# 502 Bad Gateway on Google Compute Engine, Nginx, and Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, nginx, google-compute-engine

I built a Meteor app and would like to run it on Google Compute Engine. I followed the guide found [here](https://github.com/Q42/meteor-gce) to get a basic instance of my app up and running, changing the disk size/type, the instance type, the disk and instance zones (to both match where I live), and added `export METEOR_SETTINGS={ ... }` to the second to last line of the `startup.sh` file.

Everything seemed to work fine, I have the persistent disk and vm instance listed on my Google Cloud dashboard.  I created a new firewall rule on my default network to `tcp:80`  and `tcp:443` incoming traffic, and now when I access the instance's external IP address from my browser, I'm shown a `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.8.0` page (where I'd instead expect the homepage of my Meteor app).

Is there anything in the configuration details in the [startup.sh](https://github.com/Q42/meteor-gce/blob/master/startup.sh) file that I'm missing or should modify?  Could there be an issue with how the compute vm instance is communicating with the persistent disk?  Frankly I'm far outside of my domain with this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

After ssh-ing into my instance and dinking around a bit, I called `export ROOT_URL='<the_instances_external_ip>'`, rather than 'http://localhost', at which point everything started to work.  It's unfortunate how little documentation there is on getting Meteor apps configured and running in production (I only thought to mess with ROOT_URL after searching something unrelated), so hopefully this will at least be helpful for someone else.

Comment: hi, the ROOT_URL variable didn't really exist when I ssh'd into the instance and running the `export` command didn't really do anything. Do you have any additional information please?